# WPF Custom control reset textbox text to a default value

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls

I need a text box with a button in it,it must display a default value but should still allow the user to type into a text that i need to store in my ViewModel property.
The button should reset the value to the default one.

I got few issues with this implementation:

- When the user type into the textbox i would expect the bound property in my viewModel to update accordingly, but seems there is no binding anymore. (Binding is set two way)
  (the binding and the DataContext is correct, as on load is displaying the value set from the ViewModel)
- Once i type into the box and hit the revert button the text is assign to the property as expected, but the text box still display  he same value type by the user.
- Each time i move across tabs o click another control, the button responsible for revert the text back, needs to be clicked twice (looks like a focus issue) as once the focus is in the text box all is working normally.

I have created a Generic.xaml were i have defined the control template.

```
 <Style x:Key="{x:Type local:RememberValue}" TargetType="{x:Type local:RememberValue}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource RemeberValue_Background}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource RemeberValue_Border}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource RemeberValue_Foreground}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:RememberValue}">
                    <Grid x:Name="LayoutGrid">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <baseControlUi:IconButton
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            Height="22"
                            Grid.ZIndex="1"
                            Margin="0"
                            EllipseDiameter="19"
                            Focusable="True"
                            Visibility="{Binding ElementName=RememberValueControl, Path=IsDifferentValue, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
                            ButtonCommand="{TemplateBinding RevertCommand}"
                            ButtonIcon="{StaticResource RevertIcon}" />
                        <TextBox
                            Grid.ZIndex="0"
                            Foreground="{StaticResource RemeberValue_Foreground}"
                            Text="{TemplateBinding DisplayText}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

This is the usage in the View.

```
<StackPanel Width="400">
  <remebervalue:RememberValue
    DisplayText="{Binding DisplayText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    DefaultValue="{Binding DefaultText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="400" />
</StackPanel>
```

the code behind of RemeberValue.cs ha DP registered for the DisplayText and the DefaultText

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayTextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(DisplayText), typeof(string), typeof(RememberValue), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, OnDisplayText_Changed));

public RememberValue()
{
    RevertCommand = new SimpleCommand(Revert);
}

private void Revert()
{
    DisplayText = DefaultValue;
}
    
public string DisplayText
{
 get => (string)GetValue(DisplayTextProperty);
 set => SetValue(DisplayTextProperty, value);
} 

private static void OnDisplayText_Changed(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    RememberValue RememberValue = d as RememberValue;

}
```

Comment: thanks for the replay I've edited the question. 
The ontext changed method is "empty" at the moment.

Comment: I see no issue with the `DisplayText` property and `OnDisplayText_Changed()` method. You can remove this method if you don't put anything inside, it is not mandatory to create a `FrameworkPropertyMetadata`. You might want to add `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsDifferentValue))`, though. Do you have a ViewModel where there are a `DisplayText` and `DefaultText` properties? Is the discrepancy between the names `DefaultText` and `DefaultValue` intentional? When you run your project in debug, are there no errors in the output window?

Comment: I know is not used now, I will remove it.
You are right was a copy and paste mistake. I change it to DisplayText = DefaultText;

At the moment the issue left is only on the control that needs to be clicked twice in order to trigger the command.
and I still think the issue is on focus could it be the fact im using a z index?

Comment: I rarely use z-index, so I don't know. Can you try removing it, and moving the `IconButton` after the `TextBox` in the XAML? If that doesn't solve your issue, what about adding a column to the grid and moving the button to that columun, or changing the `Grid` to a `StackPanel`?

Comment: No changes if is in agrid a panel with or without z index, I think looking at the focus is the right way as i manage to improve the usability.

setting this.
<StackPanel FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=icon}">

This allow me to click the button immediatelly, but once i toggle the tab control, a lost focus event got triggered and i still again need to click the button twice.

Comment: Hmm... If you don't find a solution to that Focus issue, you should either search for an existing solution (I'm betting it already exists on this website), and if you don't find anything, maybe ask it in a new question, as it is not the same problem as the Binding issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial answer

- First point: I believe you are mistaken in writing "Binding is set two way", as you are using `TemplateBinding`, which is [always one-way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/templatebinding-markup-extension). You should replace it with

```xml
Binding DisplayText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay
```

- Second point: fixed by the above
- Third point: different issue, needs to be addressed in a different question.

Comment: just tested your example and is working, now the binding is 2 way. (for real).